# Where does a typesetting math question go?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, meta

I have a *question about a question* (in other words a metaquestion) regarding *typesetting* exponents on the *sin* function.

The question is pretty simple.

It goes:

---

If I have a large number of terms exponentiating a sin or cos term, like this:

```
sin2 x y z2( w )
```

Is it better to write it as I have above, or to write it as

```
(sin( w ))2 x y z2
```

The extra bracketing in the second example is kind of unsightly, but the first one is kind of hard to read.

---

I'm not sure if this goes on tex.se.com, where they might not know what is standard in the math community, or math.se.com where it seems too "unmathematical".

Comment: I can't guarantee it will go over well, but I have asked a notational question before on the Math SE, which caused no problems. They even have a notation tag: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation

Answer (score 1):

That would probably fit on math.SE, since proper use of notation is part of what it takes to do math. And like Bart said in a comment, there are already notation questions there.

It doesn't seem like such a great fit on tex.SE to me, because it's not asking how to do something using TeX or one of its variants, and in fact the question is equally applicable to math written using pencil and paper. You might find a few old questions about general typography already on the site, but that's not the sort of thing it's generally meant for.